# Jquery Ajax send formdata to asp.net webpage (aspx.cs)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Below is the my ajax request

```
function sendData() {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var fileUpload = $("#txtUploadFile").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files;   
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formdata.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }
    formdata.append("PaymentDate", new Date());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'CCA_Form.aspx/SendData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
            alert("Data Added Successfully");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while inserting data");
        }
    });
}
```

and my server method is like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SendData()
    {//break point here
        // code
        return "return data";
    }
```

the ajax method always showing success message and webmethod not hitting in server side. Could you help me what i missed in my code?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a scriptmanager into your page with EnablePageMethods="True"

In C#:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string SendData(DateTime date)
  {//break point here
      // code
      return "return data";
  }
```

In aspx

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain"
        runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods="true" 
        ScriptMode="Release" 
        LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

In javascript

```
 PageMethods.SendDate(new Date(),function(response){
    // success
 });
```

And use <asp:AsyncFileUpload .. for uploading file asyncly

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="xc" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<xc:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
    OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server"
    ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern"
    OnUploadedComplete = "FileUploadComplete"
  />
 <asp:Label id="lblMsg" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Also

```
protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename  = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
     AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads/") + filename);   
}
```

And js

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete(sender)      {
        $get("<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "File Uploaded Successfully";
     }

function uploadError(sender) {
    $get("<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "File upload failed.";
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your help, but i'm not only sending the date alone, i'm sending files as well. please look at my updated question.

Comment: Use <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="asyncFileUpload" runat="server"  OnUploadedComplete="uploadFile" OnClientUploadComplete="showUploadedFiles" ThrobberID="uploading"/> for uploading files asyncly